# How can HttpContext.RequestServices fail to resolve a scoped service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, openid-connect

In an ASP.NET Core 5.0 application I'm trying to resolve a service via `HttpContext.RequestServices` and am getting an exception that it can't "Cannot resolve scoped service '...' from root provider."

Perhaps I'm missing something...Isn't the point of `HttpContext.RequestServices` to give access to the `IServiceProvider` that is scoped to the HTTP request?  Why is it returning the root provider? What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it and resolve a scoped service?

In my case this is coming from an event handler in the configuration of the OpenIdConnect middleware. The middleware configuration allows configurating of a delegate that will run during the authentication of a request and it exposes the HttpContext to the delegate function.

So I'm using some code like the following:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
        .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
        {
            // ...

            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                // This throws: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'AScopedService' from root provider.
                var myScopedService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<AScopedService>();

                // Use the service
                // Customize the context.ProtocolMessage
            };
        });
}
```

Any suggestions?

--Edit--

I was confused by similar named classes and my post was inaccurate.  I was actually trying to resolve a singleton service that depends upon a scoped service

```cs
// A singleton cannot depend upon a scoped service
// This will fail as expected
HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<SingletonServiceThatDependsOnScopedService>();
```

Thanks for helping me through my "oh duh" moment :)

Comment: Your question is missing some necessary details, but my best bet is that you are resolving an object graph that contains a singleton, and that singleton takes a direct or indirect dependency on a component with the Scoped lifestyle. Singletons are always resolved from the root scope, and with them their dependencies. This problem is called [Captive Dependency](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

Comment: as far as I know singletons cannot depend on scoped dependencies and this will be validated *in development environment* with an error being thrown. So looks like you've not even tried your code in the development environment (debugging)?

Comment: Thank you @Steven you are absolutely correct.  I had classes with similar names and got confused.  My post was incorrect, the service I was directly trying to resolve was registered as a singleton but depended on a service registered as scoped. That makes sense why it would fail.  I'll edit my post to make my error clear.  Thank you!!